# PHP preg_replace with newlines

Tags: php, regex

Got text a little like this coming out of a database

```
[color=#BF0000]This is just a very simple test. 
Cheers Fred[/color]
```

Now this text could have newlines anywhere in it between the `[color...]` and `[/color]`.

Been trying to use this regex within preg_replace, this is the pattern

```
\[color=(#[0-9a-f]{3}|#[0-9a-f]{6}|[a-z\-]+)\](.*?)\[\/color\]/i
```

and gets replaced with

```
<span style=\"color:$1\">$2</span>
```

All works great if there are no newlines in the text. I know I need to make changes around `(.*?)` but no idea what, can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `s` modifier to make dot match newlines:

```
'~\[color=(#[0-9a-f]{3}|#[0-9a-f]{6}|[a-z-]+)\](.*?)\[/color\]~is'
```

Also you can use an alternate regex delimiter to avoid escaping forward slash.

Comment: *Groan* as simple at that, I'd tried all ways but that, thanks